# Does proximity search work? It doesn't for me

Tags: geocoding, advanced-search

I tried to show someone how proximity search in 'Advanced Search' worked and - it didn't.  The message was 'We could not geocode the destination address'.  Despite the postcode being one that created a map when saved as the contact address - so it could be geocoded. This is using the OpenStreetMap geocoding extension and I tried using releases 5.49.5 and also 5.53 but both failed. I tried both a specific postcode and a range.  Maybe a bug in advanced search?

Comment: I don't know about openstreetmap but try filling in country and other fields. I remember it not being tolerant about some fields missing.

Comment: I added the country but it didn't help, which was an unwelcome surprise because I'm pretty sure I ran across this before.  Same message as before.  However... it works in 5.49.5 but doesn't work in 5.53.  So I guess I should raise as an issue in 5.53.  Oddly, proximity search is missing on dmaster - has it been removed?

Comment: Re. my above comment, after adding the Geocoder extension on dmaster, proximity search appears and works (5.56 alpha1).  So not sure why 5.53 doesn't as I can't see any issues for proximity searches

Comment: It seems ok for me if I use 5.53. Not sure what else it could be. Maybe another extension or setting.

Comment: After trying out the Geocoder extension & Google geocoding (neither worked) I went back to OpenStreetMaps and it's now working in 5.53.  No idea why...